# How to use Webjob to call method in WebApp in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, web-applications, cron

I need to call methods every hour in my web app (aspnet core MVC)  which is published on Azure.
Basically Azure gives opportunity to create webjob in "the context of webapp". How can I use webjob to call methods in webapp. As I understand for webjob I need to create seperate project and then deploy it, but can I link parameters or call methods from webjob?

Also how can access webapp wwwroot with webjob program?

Comment: The WebJob is a separate project that gets published to a special location within your Web App Service.  When you say "How can I use webjob to call methods in webapp", are you simply trying to reuse logic/services within the context of the WebJob?  Or are you actually trying to call a method on the running web app (like RPC style)?

Comment: Thanks fro your answer Bryan. I thought you can call Webapp methods from webjob project . Basically I need to update database from api every hour. I was thinking to make method with timer which will call method every hour, but people say it snot good in the long term. So now i m thinking to create special route in the webapp , and  in the webjob console project just enter the link every hour. Is there better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I would recommend one of two options.  The first would be if you just need to update the database, and any logic to do that update can be easily contained within the WebJob itself, then just run the WebJob as a cron process, connect directly to the database in the WebJob, and do the update from there.  This is the best option if this DB update doesn't depend on any state or info on the running Web app.

If you want to actually go through the WebApp, then you notion of creating a route/endpoint on the webapp (protect it in some way!) that calls you necessary method(s) and then have your WebJob use HttpClient to make a web request to that route every hour.

The code for this second option would be very simple, something like:

```
public static async Task UpdateTimer(["0 0 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation($"Timer Invoked: {DateTime.Now}");
   var httpClient = new HttpClient();
   await httpClient.GetAsync("https://my.url.com/special-route");            
}
```

Both of these options really don't have to be a WebJob either.  They could also be run as a separate Azure Function, which works similar to a WebJob but doesn't actually run within the context of the WebApp and allows it to be managed separately -- if that could be a benefit.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for this. We have an endpoint in our WebApp that needs to be available via HTTP, but also trigger every day at a specific time. It takes about an hour to complete, so we can't use Functions because they timeout. This sounds like what we need.